# Matching article text against pre-existing list of categories

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

I'm new to Azure Cognitive Services, and while I'm pretty sure it ***can*** help me solve my problem, I don't quite understand which part of it to use for it...

Here's what I want to do:

We have blog posts, say ~1k, and those blog posts all have categories and tags (multiple each). What I want to do, is to "guess" the right categories/tags for each article based on the content, and then present that to the editor as a suggestions at the time of input ("looks like this article is about: health, well-being, ..."). The ~1k articles we already have in the system are currently correctly tagged/categorized, so I'd like to use these a data source for this "guessing".

I've used Azure Search before, and it seems like some combination of EntityRecognition and KeyPhraseExtraction might be a way in the right direction? Azure Cognitive Services also seems to have an API that supports TextAnalytics that would do something similar. I'm a bit confused about why these are two different things (or are they not?)

This also seems like an entirely common problem (matching text against pre-defined categories based on other text that is categorized), so I'm wondering if I'm just missing an obvious solution here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Azure Cognitive Text Analytics API is your best bet as you are looking for real-time analysis prior to tagging/categorizing for storage.

Text Analytics could return a list of named entities that you could map to your available tags/categories and present to the user.

Azure Cognitive Search requires an indexer and skillset to process target text with an end result of storing the processed results to an index specifically for searching.